# How to import large sql file in phpmyadmin xampp

Tags: php, file-upload

How can i import 4gb sql file of phpmyadmin?

I increased upload_max_filesize to 4G, max_execution_time to 900, post_max_size to 4G in php.ini file but still it shows "Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration."
Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to upload the script file in your own PHP script? Or within a phpmyadmin screen? It wasn't really clear. Either way, 4GB is probably too big to upload on the web. Maybe SFTP it to the server and run the import via mysql command prompt or similar.

Comment: you can use the command :
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql